Filtering dates through formulas (using the current and 'dot notation'
I have two databases, Matrix and Log in Notion. They are related.
The Matrix table has columns including "Employee" (rollup to Staff database), "Mar & Apr", "May & Jun", "Jul & Aug", etc. The Log table has columns including Topic, Employee (the rollup), Meeting Type, Date Done.
I would like it that the Matrix database for that employee shows the log dates that are applicable to each column, ie any logs with a Date Done of March or April show the dates in that column).
I can NEARLY get there, using the code:
ifs(
map(prop("Log"),current.prop("Employee") == prop("Employee")),map(prop("Log"),current.prop("Date Done").formatDate("DD/MM/YYYY")))

But I've tried and tried to get it to show only those records in that date range, including trying inserting the code:
map(prop("Log"),current.prop("Date Done").dateRange(formatDate("01/03/2024","DD/MM/YYYY"),"30/04/2024")

Is this possible? If so, how?
